# Why some other value than zero is coming in first row?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, initialization, variable-length-array

I'm trying to make an `MxN` zero matrix using an array in `C++`. But some values aren't coming zero. Please help me resolve this problem.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int m,n;
cin>>m>>n;
int i,j,s[m][n]={0};
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        cout<<s[i][j]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
}
```

**input:** 4 4

**output:**

```
0 11097 1757549776 11097 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0
```

**expected ouput:**

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

Comment: `s[m][n] = {0}` is not even valid C++.    Try using a `std::vector>std::vector<int> >` instead.    For example,  `std::vector<std::vector<int> > s(m, std::vector<int>(n))` will give you the behaviour you expect.

Answer (score 1):

This code is not valid in standard C++ because it does not allow dynamic array creation without `new` like this.

For example, here is VC++ output: https://rextester.com/VFVL26633

```
ource_file.cpp(9): note: failure was caused by non-constant arguments or reference to a non-constant symbol
source_file.cpp(9): note: see usage of 'm'
source_file.cpp(14): warning C4552: '<<': operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect
source_file.cpp(18): error C2036: 'int [m][n]': unknown size
```

If you make `n`, `m` const it will work correctly.

Use `std::vector` or `new`/`delete`.

Comment: Several compilers support VLAs as a non-standard extension.

Comment: @Peter: True, but that means you can't count on them implementing the _same_ non-standard extension. For instance, this exact problem (zero initialization) might be inconsistent across compilers.

Comment: @MSalters - No argument on that.  Context of my previous comment was the original posting of this answer, which used more tentative language than it does now.  (It appears the answer was edited to its current form about an hour before your comment).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but probably it's because the size of the matrix is dynamic and the compiler can't generate initializer in compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

`s[m][n]={0}` initialization is only valid when you know the size of the matrix in compiling time, you need use memset or a loop to initialize this matrix. using memset is very easy : `memset(s,0,m*m*sizeof(int))`

Comment: The question is tagged C++, not C. VLA's don't exist in C++, and you'd use `std::fill`.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning size of static matrix/array in the form of variable is prohibited. You have to give the size at compile time or use dynamic arrays.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i, j, s[4][4] = { 0 };
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            cout << s[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare array `s` its dimensions should be known in the compile time.
As you did not initialize explicitly `m` and `n`, they are both initialized with some random values and used for `s` array declaration.
So your `s` array could have any random dimensions (maybe zero) and after entering `m` and `n` from `cin` you might be just printing some uninitialized memory cells.

Comment: You may want to recheck the code. The values of `m` and `n` are read from standard input. Regardless, even if that wasn't the case, they wouldn't be "initialized with random values" (unspecified behavior), they'd be **uninitialized** (Undefined Behavior).

Comment: The `m` and `n` are read from the standard input indeed, but for the array declaration at the compile time they don't have those values from the standard input yet. Right, the variables are uninitialized so at the array declaration time they could have any values.

Comment: this is a VLA (variable length) array. The doc says that initialization of VLA is not supported, so the array elements are not padded with 0 like it would be done for a constant size array

Answer (score 0):

Use an empty bracket {} to initialize the array. This will initialize all elements of the array to null by default.